# How to find exact matching number from comma separated string in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a column in database, it contains error codes like "2,3,7,5,6,17" and I have taken it as a string and I want to exact match digit using linq.

For example I want to find match 7 (This number is taking dynamically) inside this string then it will return true. But the problem is, string also contain 17 so its fetching row which contains 17 also even if 7 is not present. I have used Contains() for that. Kindly give me the exact solution of it so I can return rows where we got exact match inside this string.

Note: This string I am fetching from the Database using LINQ

[Image to show Rows fetched from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJbYk.png)

In this image you can see the number 17 row also fetched but it doesn't contain 7. I want only for the 7 (exact match only)

Code that I have used

```
List<TableModel> result = from DN in dbContext.Example where DN.ErrorType.Contains(ErrorTypetxt).Select({})
```

**DN.ErrorType is a complete string fetched from the db i.e 2,3,7,5,6,17**

**ErrorTypetxt is a 7 that I want to exact match..**

How to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure if this is efficient but `DN.ErrorType.StartsWith(7) || DN.ErrorType.Contains(",7,") || DN.ErrorType.EndsWith(",7") `? Wouldnt a child table be helpful that contains these values which links to this table?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: false positive `123,71`: note that `,7` will be found; it should be something like this: `StartsWith("7,") || Contains(",7,") || EndsWith(",7")`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Yes, corrected it. I dont know if this is a good way to handle such a scenario though.

Comment: What is your database? You may be able to use something like [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thats not the correct answer. if our number for example 1 is in 4th position then and also 14 is present there then how can we solve it? your code giving rows only starts with 1 if the 1 is in another position then? in OR condition if first true then it not check for the second

Comment: I have updated query in question

Comment: The right answer is, don't store delimited lists as strings in your relational database and then try to query based on parts of the list. If you have many rows the query will be slow, if the formatting of the list has any variable whitespace, the query will be unreliable. Instead, the values should be stored in a table with a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = 7;
var start = $"{num},";
var end = $",{num}";
var mid = $",{num},";
var same = $"{num}";

var query =
  from dn in source
  where
    dn.ErrorType.StartsWith(start) ||
    dn.ErrorType.Contains(mid) ||
    dn.ErrorType.EndsWith(end) ||
    dn.ErrorType == same
  select dn;
```

Or

```
var num = 7;
var mid = $",{num},";

var query =
  from dn in source
  let modified = "," + dn.ErrorType + ","
  where modified.Contains(mid)
  select dn;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var expected = "7";
var queryResult = "1,2,17,7";
var splitResult = queryResult.Split(',');
bool result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(splitResult.FirstOrDefault(s => string.Equals(s, expected)));
//returns true
```

Comment: Its giving me error that can not convert from bool to string,bool

Comment: Edited to return a boolean. But not sure what kind of method signature/return type you are looking for?

Comment: I just want true or false if there is a match and storing into the List result = query.. means storing as a list. you have changed the variable to bool but i want query which returns bool true or false

Comment: we can not use split because I am taking string from model..

Comment: The question is not how to match one value in a comma-separated string. That's trivial. The problem is how to do it in a database field.

Comment: @GertArnold you are right it is trivial; my mistake, I misunderstood the question. I did not see that we were talking specifically about sql linq. I presume then regex is not an option either?

Comment: No, it won't translate into SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this using split first and then use the contain.
Please check this
https://dotnetfiddle.net/80k13h

**Update after the first comment:**
use this structure

```
TestTables
.Where(x => 
    ("," + x.Subjects + ",").Contains(",7,") ||
    (x.Subjects.EndsWith("7") && x.Subjects.Length == 1) ||
    (x.Subjects.StartsWith("7,") && x.Subjects.Length == 2) ||
    (x.Subjects.Contains(",7,") && x.Subjects.Length > 2 && 
        x.Subjects[0] != '7' && x.Subjects[x.Subjects.Length - 1] != '7')
)
.ToList()
```

This generates the following SQL in linqpad as give the expected result.
[image]